# Filtering objects from array with matching attribute from another array, in the other array's order

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have come across this issue more than once during my career.  I have googled and have not found a precise match in those results or on StackOverflow.

Consider that I have the following array of objects:

```
let objects = [
    {id: 'doe', descr: 'a deer'},
    {id: 'baz', descr: 'non-sense'},
    {id: 'ray', descr: 'a drop'},
    {id: 'foo', descr: 'effed'},
    {id: 'bar', descr: 'beyond'}
];
```

I would like to get only the array elements where `id` matches one of the elements of the following array, *and* returns them in an array that matches the *order* of the following:

```
let objectsOrder = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
```

I've actually devised a couple of solutions, and will be presenting one as an answer using `reduce` below (I've also used `forEach` in other attempts but will not be presenting that).  I guess it could also be done by first filtering, then (custom) sorting, but that would seem to iterate twice.  Maybe another alternative is to use a method (or methods) from `lodash`, though I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: Try `objectsOrder.map(a=>objects.find(b=>b.id==a))`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Make it an answer please

Comment: no attempt ...?

Comment: @NinaScholz My attempt is my answer: 'I've actually devised a couple of solutions, and will be presenting one as an answer'

Comment: @GeorgeJempty that attempt should actually be a part of question seeking for improvement.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Not necessarily, if you've ever asked a question, there is an option on that page for answering your own question

Comment: @GeorgeJempty this is a forceful question with a forceful answer. Not relevant.

Comment: Seems to me the easiest and simple way would be to simply convert the objects to be `keyed` by the id. Then it is a simply getting values from an object by key. Posted a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get map the objects in the wanted order.

```js
var objects = [
        { id: 'doe', descr: 'a deer' }, 
        { id: 'baz', descr: 'non-sense' }, 
        { id: 'ray', descr: 'a drop' }, 
        { id: 'foo', descr: 'effed' }, 
        { id: 'bar', descr: 'beyond' }
    ],
    objectsOrder = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    result = objectsOrder.map(Map.prototype.get, new Map(objects.map(o => [o.id, o])));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If some `id` are unknown, you could add a filter for truthy items.

```js
var objects = [
        { id: 'doe', descr: 'a deer' }, 
        { id: 'baz', descr: 'non-sense' }, 
        { id: 'ray', descr: 'a drop' }, 
        { id: 'foo', descr: 'effed' }, 
        { id: 'bar', descr: 'beyond' }
    ],
    objectsOrder = ['foo', 'bar', 'unknown'],
    result = objectsOrder
        .map(Map.prototype.get, new Map(objects.map(o => [o.id, o])))
        .filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please format this better (so the lines aren't so long) thanks -- I'd do it myself but have to leave shortly.

Comment: which line is too long? maybe hit refresh first?

Comment: How does `Map.prototype.get` know to look in thisArg param?

Comment: `Map.prototype.get` is the function/cb and map takes the function and uses it with `thisArg`, the instance of `Map`.

Comment: If the object is not in `objects`, `result` will have an undesired null in its place

Comment: @GeorgeJempty, you could ad a filter for truthy values.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is at: https://repl.it/@dexygen/orderFilteredObjects

```
let objects = [
    {id: 'doe', descr: 'a deer'},
    {id: 'baz', descr: 'non-sense'},
    {id: 'ray', descr: 'a drop'},
    {id: 'foo', descr: 'effed'},
    {id: 'bar', descr: 'beyond'}
];

let objectsOrder = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

let prunedObjects = objects.reduce((pruned, obj) => {
    let orderIndex = objectsOrder.indexOf(obj.id);
    if (orderIndex >= 0) {
      pruned[orderIndex] = obj;
    }
    return pruned;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(prunedObjects)); //[{"id":"foo","descr":"effed"},{"id":"bar","descr":"beyond"},{"id":"baz","descr":"non-sense"}]
```

Comment: This will continue re-scanning the `objectsOrder` array to find a match for *each* of the entries in `objects`. It would be way easier to build a lookup hash from `objectsOrder` first - reducing it to `{ foo: 0, bar: 1, baz: 2 }` in one operation and then doing `orderIndex = order[obj.id]` to simply fetch the value.

Comment: @vlaz I thought arrays were optimized for indexOf any more?  However you are right, if I'm not getting the order from some other source, it would be better to make it an object, not an array.

Comment: It would still trigger a scan of the array for O(n). Because there are two arrays involved, the complexity would be O(n^m) where `n` length of `objectsOrder` and `m` is the length of `objects`. Pre-computing a hash would be O(n) and each fetch afterwards will be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with a `forEach()` loop. No need to use `reduce()`.

```js
let objects = [
    {id: 'doe', descr: 'a deer'},
    {id: 'baz', descr: 'non-sense'},
    {id: 'ray', descr: 'a drop'},
    {id: 'foo', descr: 'effed'},
    {id: 'bar', descr: 'beyond'}
];

let objectsOrder = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
let res = [];
objects.forEach((obj)=>{
  var id = obj.id;
  var idIndex = objectsOrder.indexOf(id);
  if(idIndex !== -1){
    res[idIndex] = obj;
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: And that `.forEach` could easily be the more appropriate `.filter`

Comment: @vlaz not following you. Please come again

Comment: There is no need to loop and build up a new array of filtered objects when `Array.filter` exists for exactly this purpose. `objects.filter(obj => objectsOrder.includes(obj.id))` is all that's needed.

Comment: @vlaz `filter` by itself is not enough, the results need to come out in a particular order.  Using `filter` first requires iterating *again*

Comment: OK, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to get the input data in a form which suits an object key access via lodash [_.keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#keyBy):

```js
let objects = [{id: 'doe', descr: 'a deer'},{id: 'baz', descr: 'non-sense'},{id: 'ray', descr: 'a drop'},{id: 'foo', descr: 'effed'},{id: 'bar', descr: 'beyond'}];
let objectsOrder = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

var keyedObjects = _.keyBy(objects, 'id')
var result = objectsOrder.map(x => keyedObjects[x])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This way you map on `objectsOrder` to preserve the order and simply use the key to get the access in the map function.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need such a complex logic. Simply map each `objectsOrder` value and get the corresponding value on your `objects` array

```js
let objects = [
    {id: 'doe', descr: 'a deer'},
    {id: 'baz', descr: 'non-sense'},
    {id: 'ray', descr: 'a drop'},
    {id: 'foo', descr: 'effed'},
    {id: 'bar', descr: 'beyond'}
];

let objectsOrder = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

console.log(
  objectsOrder.map(a=>objects.find(b=>b.id==a))
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a `O(n2)` complexity `find` inside `map`.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I wasnt referring to complexity in my answer, apologize if seems so. In deed my answer is `O(n*n)` but OP didnt specified he was looking for a fastest algorithm, just a solution for his problem.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal it's O(n^m) because the two arrays are of different length.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I don't have a problem I can't solve per se since I posted my own solution as an answer. In which case I wouldn't want an alternative algorithm which is O(n*n), since mine with reduce is faster than that.